# Refreshing websites and temporary connection loss

Tags: web, refresh, page-refresh, browser-refresh

I want to display a refeshing external Website continously on a monitor.
The Website already contains an internal refresh (let's say every 30 seconds).

The Problem that appears right now is that in case of any connection loss the website tries to reload himself but will end up in a "connection has timed out state" and will no longer refresh. (because it's locked out).

What is the simplest way to avoid this "deadlock"?
I've already thought about having a Local Webpage that refreshs after a certain time, but this would cause a double refresh because the Webpage itself already refreshes every "n seconds".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>Insert Title Here</title></head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
   <iframe style="margin:0;padding:0;border:0;width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
   <script>
      var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
      setInterval(function(){
         iframe.src = iframe.src;
      }, 5000);
   </script>
</body>
```

Set the `5000` to `n-1` seconds in milliseconds. (e.g., if `n=30`, use `29000`)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdbNN/